# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, xcode, pytorch

I tried to implement the code from PyTorch Tutorial, and it seems there is an issue with libc++abi.dylib:

[image]

Comment: Error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BRiM.png

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling my xcode.